# Neo4j | Cypher - given node A, show me path to node B of C type which has more than X children of D type

Tags: neo4j, cypher

First part of query is to find nodes of type **C** which have more than **X** children of **D** type and I have this working:

```
MATCH (Parent:$C)
WITH Parent, [(Child:$D)-[]-(Parent) | Child] as children
WITH Parent, children, size(children) as ChildCount
WHERE ChildCount > $X

RETURN Parent
```

Now I'd like to take node **A** and find a Path to some of nodes returned from first query.
My query looks like this:

```
//Part A - this one is already working
MATCH (Parent:FullAddress)
WITH Parent, [(Child:Company)-[]-(Parent) | Child] as children
WITH Parent, children, size(children) as ChildCount
WHERE ChildCount > 10
WITH Parent as Target

//Part B - this part doesn't work
MATCH Path = (S:Ship)-[*2]-(Target)
WHERE ID(S)=164758
RETURN nodes(Path)
LIMIT 100
```

The expected result is to show me path between `Ship` with `ID=164758` and one of nodes from **query A**. I am sure that this path exists as I checked it manually before choosing query parameters.

Current result is neo4j loadig to infinity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the query was just too big to handle for neo4j as I have 5,000,000+ nodes.